# 言語kotlinの->はラムダ式でしょうか？

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

```
ApiManager.getSuggestions(newText, {

                        receiver ->

                        val keywords = receiver.receive()

                        if (keywords.isEmpty()) {

                            self.updateKeywordList(arrayOf(newText), "このキーワードで検索")

                        } else {

                            self.updateKeywordList(keywords, "以下のキーワードで検索")

                        }


                    }
```

言語コトリンについて質問させてください
質問１　->はラムダ式でしょうか？
質問２　receiverに対してどんな処理が行われていますか？
質問３　オブジェクトApiManagerに対してどんな処理が行われています？

いただいた解答によってkotlinとAndroidについて理解を深めようとしています。
質問の仕方が悪いかもしれませんがご指摘いただければ直したいと思います。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問1

はい。
->はラムダ式の引数リストとボディを分けるための記号です。

質問2, 3

実際のコードを見ないことには何とも言えませんが
receiverはgetSuggestionsの結果のコールバック関数の引数のようです。
receiver.receive()で、受け取った結果のキーワードを取得しているようですね。